# How can I map data from service to a local JSON object

Tags: angular

I have a local array of object as below :

```
maritalStatusOptions = [
        {"option": "Marital Status" },
        {"option": "Divorced" },
        {"option": "Married/Domestic Partner" },
        {"option": "Seperated" },
        {"option": "MI" },
        {"option": "Single" },
        {"option": "Widowed" }
    ];
```

I receive the user's marital status from my service response as "M", which means he is married.

How can I map this "M" to **"Married/Domestic Partner"** in my local object array?

My HTML is as follows:

```
<select class="marital-status" [(ngModel)]="selectedStatus" (ngModelChange)="CheckStatus($event)">
     <option *ngFor="let status of maritalStatusOptions">{{status.option}}</option>  
</select>
```

Comment: I guess you would need to answer the question how you want to map it. You can create an object that maps from one value to the other and then access it in the binding.

Comment: I want to set my ngModel to "Married/Domestic Partner" when my response is "M".

Comment: personally, i would have the marital status options in it's own table, on the server I would work with an enum to map that and on the client, in angular, you could easily map it by the Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear from your question what you try to accomplish.

An attempt: You can create an object that allows from one value to the other

```ts
maritalStatusMap = {
        A: "Marital Status",
        B: "Divorced",
        M: "Married/Domestic Partner",
        C: "Seperated",
        D: "MI",
        D: "Single",
        E: "Widowed"
    };
```

And then get the value (I assume `status.option` is `'M'`) by passing `status.option` to `martialStatusMap[...]`, which in this case would return `"Married/Domestic Partner"`

```ts
<select class="marital-status" [(ngModel)]="selectedStatus" (ngModelChange)="CheckStatus($event)">
     <option *ngFor="let status of maritalStatusOptions">{{maritalStatusMap[status.option]}}</option>  
</select>
```

Comment: Really sorry for not being clear in my question. My value is actually being set in "selectedStatus", which is my ngModel. Although I took your idea and used maritalStatusMap[selectedStatus] in my ngModel and it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot for helping me resolve this. @Günter Zöchbauer

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)